# Vue replaces "open" attribute to value "open" in any tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, attributes, mathml

I'm using vue.js (v2.6.12) components in laravel blade templates.
For the project, I'm also using MathML in which I need to use the `open` attribute of `<mfenced>` tag to be set to some custom values. Here is the example of the math expressing in mathml.

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi>f</mi>
    <mfenced close="]" open="[">
        <mrow><mi>a</mi><mo>,</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow>
    </mfenced>
</math>
```

But as soon as the page renders, the `open` attribute is converted into this `open="open"`. I'm 100% sure there is no other library or script is loaded that updates like so, just plain vue. This actually breaks the math expression. So it looks like this:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi>f</mi>
    <mfenced close="]" open="open">
        <mrow><mi>a</mi><mo>,</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow>
    </mfenced>
</math>
```

Later I realized that not only in math expression, litaratily any tag, be it `<div open="anything">...</div>`, `<span open="anything">...</span>`, `<custom-element open="something">...</custom-element>` having `open` attribute behaves the same. even if I use `v-pre` attribute to exclude it from vue js templete compiler.

And this do not happen, as soon I disable the vue app initialization.

---

The question here are:

1. Why vue is changing the open attribute like so?
2. How can I stop this behaviour, to the entire page within the vue application area or at least where I choose (something like using `v-pre`), is there ary config or any other way around?

Comment: You sound like you've done your research in debugging here, but I can't think of anything in Vue alone that would cause this behavior... This is really strange. I know you say you're sure there's no other libraries at play here, but I'm inclined to believe that something else *has* to be at play here. Are you using any other Vue libraries elsewhere in your project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a simple hack to solve this problem.

**Why hack?**

Because it is eventually going to be fixed in the comming release as pointed by @Michal, so just a quick & dirty hack is enough for now to go for it.

What I did is I placed the math content in the content and also added it to the data attribute and replacing the original content after vue has done its bad work (sorry just using blade syntax here, but it will make sense). I keep it in both places just for SEO purposes.

The template where I need math expression to be displayed.

```php
...
<div class="proxy-content" data-proxy-content="{{ $article->content }}">
    {!! $article->content !!}
</div>
...
```

I was using it along with jQuery, but you can easily substitute with vue.js' `$el`. This is what it looks in my `app.js` file.

```js
...
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    methods: {

        proxyContent() {
            // Set Proxy Content.
            jQuery('.proxy-content').each((i, el) => {
                const $el = jQuery(el);
                $el.html( jQuery('<textarea />').html( $el.data('proxy-content')).text() );
            });
        }
        
        loadMathJax() {
            // Load & Initialize MathJax Library.
            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src  = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        }

    }

    mounted(){
        // Enable proxy content after mount, so we are sure no more rendering issue for templates.
        this.proxyContent();

        // Load MathJax library with a little delay to make sure everything is ready before loading the library.
        setTimeout(() => this.loadMathJax(), 10);
    }
});
...
```

One might argue, that I'm mixing up things outside of the scope of the vue application. For me that is not an issue, as the whole page is using `vue.js` and also the single thing don't make any harm even if there is another scope that is using `mathml` (though it depends on actual implementation).

In that case, if you want to scope it well, just use `$el` of vue.

Answer (score 1):

### Why

In HTML spec there are some attributes called [boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes). Spec dictates what can be a value of such attribute:

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

`open` is one of the boolean attributes - it is defined for the `<details>` [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)

Problem with Vue 2 is, that it treats most of the [boolean attributes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0ff1356ef7922f9c082a11fd2ec9124539468a6b/src/platforms/web/util/attrs.js#L33) as global - without considering the element it is placed on. Result is that `open` attribute is always rendered with value "open" or removed if the value is falsy (when `v-bind`ing). This is fixed in Vue 3 as shown in 2nd example...

### How

The use of `v-pre` is the way to go but unfortunately for you there is a bug.
See [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10087). The bug was already fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/0664cb01434f3d52efd076b6aafe54066a2a762a)(Sep 21, 2020) but it was not released yet...

1. example - the "With v-pre" should work in Vue version > 2.6.12

   ```js
   const vm = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data() {
       return {
         message: 'Hi!',
         html: `<div open="[" close="]">Hi from html</div>`
       }
     },
   })
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
   <div id="app">
     <div open="[" close="]">{{ message }}</div>
     <div v-html="html"></div>
     <div v-pre>
       <p open="[" close="]">With v-pre</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. example - it works in Vue 3 - `open` is treated as boolean attribute only if placed on `<details>`

   ```js
   const app = Vue.createApp({
     data() {
       return {
         message: 'This works in Vue 3!',
       }
     },
   })

   app.mount('#app')
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.11/vue.global.js" integrity="sha512-1gHWIGJfX0pBsPJHfyoAV4NiZ0wjjE1regXVSwglTejjna0/x/XG8tg+i3ZAsDtuci24LLxW8azhp1+VYE5daw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

   <div id="app">
     <div open="[" close="]">{{ message }}</div>
     <details open="[">
       <summary>Details</summary>
       open attribute on details element is treated as boolean (renders empty value)
     </details>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to create a [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-directive) (named `"attr"`) that sets the attribute:

```js
Vue.directive('attr', (el, binding) => el.setAttribute(binding.arg, binding.value || ''))
```

Then use it in your template like `v-bind` but with `v-attr`:

```html
<mfenced v-attr:open="'['">
```

```js
Vue.directive('attr', (el, binding) => el.setAttribute(binding.arg, binding.value || ''))

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

<div id="app">
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi>f</mi>
    <mfenced close="]" v-attr:open="'['">
      <mrow><mi>a</mi><mo>,</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow>
    </mfenced>
  </math>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is good, but sometime we don't have the oppertunity to modify / hook into the editor using which we are creating the math expressions the first place. I've found a KISS wayout for this issue, explaining on my answer.